# How to install Laravel 4.2 / 5 on Windows Server 2008 with IIS?

Tags: php, iis, laravel, windows-server-2008, laravel-5

I am trying to install Laravel 4.2 in a **Windows Server 2008 x64** machine.

The server is already hosting more than 30 Raw PHP, PHP [Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/), WordPress and Joomla websites with MySQL DB.

What I have done is just copy and pest the code from another Windows WAMP server and set up database. But it is not working.

Then I have trying to use [this](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/installing-laravel-4-in-windows-7-with-iis7/) tutorial to work, but I also fail again.

Can anyone please tell me how can I configure the server so that I can run PHP Laravel in that server without making any problem to another sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation

The Laravel framework has a few system requirements:

```
PHP >= 5.5.9
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
```

See also: http://tutsnare.com/install-laravel-via-laravel-installer-windows/

And also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDR1YYaHJzs

Comment: I know it, actually everyone know it. It is not what I am looking for.